# Ender 3 Pro not auto homing

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, bed-leveling, bltouch

I have had my Ender 3 Pro for roughly a year now and have decided to make some upgrades.

I recently upgraded to a BLTouch and silent board. I am having a problem auto homing where the printer does its usual homing process until it gets to the z axis. It simply doesn't move and displays "STOPPED" on the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Clearly something whent wrong in the "upgrade" process. You should provide more information on the upgrades you have performed. Especially, how the BLTouch is connected and configured in firmware. If you have fixed the issue by now, maybe add the answer so others may learn from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would revisit and start again on your firmware. Sounds to me as if the printer is getting confused as to which Z Endstop it should be looking at.